# How do i get the names of an (sub-)object without having indices added in R?

Tags: r, names

I want to get the names of an (sub-)object (so all resulting objects after `unlist`) without having indices added in R.

(Simplified) sample data:  (See remark at the end for more complex data).

```
lst <- list(
  a = data.frame(b = 1, c = c(1, 2, 3), "d2" = 5, "x21" = 3)
)
```

Expected output:

```
c("b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d2", "d2", "d2", "x21", "x21", "x21")
```

Current output:

```
  > unlist(lst) %>% names
[1] "aa"       "b.x"      "b.a.b1"   "b.a.b2"   "b.a.b3"   "b.a.c1"   "b.a.c2"   "b.a.c3"   "b.a.d21"  "b.a.d22"  "b.a.d23"  "b.a.x211" "b.a.x212"
[14] "b.a.x213"
```

What i tried:

```
lapply(lst, names)
```

Getting closer. But note that this is simplified data, the target data.frame could be nested within
3+ parent lists.

```
lst <- list(
  list(aa = 1,
       b = list(x = 2, 
                a = data.frame(b = 1, c = c(1, 2, 3), "d2" = 5, "x21" = 3)
       )
  )
)
```

I wanted to start Splitting by Point and then check in the resulting values (b1, b2, b3) or (d21, d22, d23) for a pattern and remove the number if a clear pattern like (1-10) is detected. But it seemed like 
quite a Workaround.  So i wanted to ask if there is a better way to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a better way, but this would get you the output:

```
lst <- rlist::list.flatten(lst)

unlist(
  unname(
    Map(
      function(x, y) sub('.*\\.', '', rep(x, each = y)),
      names(lst),
      sapply(lst, length)
    )
  )
)
```

Your second example:

```
 [1] "aa"  "x"   "b"   "b"   "b"   "c"   "c"   "c"   "d2"  "d2"  "d2"  "x21" "x21"
[14] "x21"
```

Data:

```
lst <- list(
  list(aa = 1,
       b = list(x = 2, 
                a = data.frame(b = 1, c = c(1, 2, 3), "d2" = 5, "x21" = 3)
       )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) rep(names(x), each=nrow(x)))
```

Returns:

```
$a
[1] "b"   "b"   "b"   "c"   "c"   "c"   "d2"  "d2"  "d2"  "x21" "x21" "x21"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I like the idea of nrow. I am not sure it would adress the issue concerning the last Code snippet when the target data.frame is nested within other lists.

Comment: i upvoted. Since the other answers also covers the second test case, i accepted it. Hope that is fine. Thank you!

Comment: That's absolutely fine! The arg0naut91s answer is excellent! Have a nice day!